# Dynamically loading live video streams HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, stream, adobe, http-live-streaming

Looking for pointer in the right direction 
I want to create a dynamically loading live video stream player and playlist in HTML 5, The Streams are coming from Adobe Media Server.
I have no idea how many streams are coming in! so i need advice or even if someone has come across any tutorials of documentation on how to go about doing it it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what's the streaming format? HTML5 doesn't support much streaming...

Comment: its streaming down in HTTP i have single streams playing from a custom player that plays manifest files called by a URL is a hybrid version of HLS and other streaming formats so it plays .m3u8 ,f4m,ism

Comment: ok, then the videos can likely play, good news. a playlist isn't quite right for streaming: since streams don't end, the playlist won't advance. in principle, you need a simple lightbox script that supports iframes or <video> instead of just <img>. you should be able to show the video simply by showing some html.

Comment: Thanks for that really appreciate it will give that a go now :-)